# What is the syntax to delete a cell using the UI Automation instrument?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, instruments, ios-ui-automation

I am working on a UI Automation script to test a page in my application that contains many cells.

I have an option to edit and save the page.  On clicking "edit" an option will appear to delete a cell.  I would like to make my script delete or add a cell at this point.  How can I get the script to do this?

Answer (score 3):

With element index :

```
myCell.switches().[0].tap();
myCell.buttons().[0].tap();
```

Or with predicate :

```
myCell.switches().firstWithPredicate("name contains[c] 'Delete'").tap();
myCell.buttons().firstWithPredicate("name contains[c] 'Confirm'").tap();
```